# what is the correct syntax jquery function for a dynamic content

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, image, popover

i show a dynamic table with an element where I want to show and image when hover.

my dynamic table is like this :

```
$('#submitElement').on('click', function() {

  var modeleID = $('input[type="radio"][name="modele"]:checked').val();

  //populate table

  tr = $('<tr/>');

  tr.append("<td><i id='prodImg" + formOffre.modele.value +"' class='nc-icon nc-alert-circle-i' data-toggle='popover-hover' data-img=''></i></td>");
  tr.append("<td id='prod" + formOffre.modele.value +"'></td>");
  tr.append("<td>" + formOffre.longueur.value + " x " + formOffre.hauteur.value  + "</td>");
  tr.append("<td>" + (formOffre.prix.value/formOffre.qte.value) + "</td>");
  $('#offretable').prepend(tr);

  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'/includes/ajaxData2.php',
    data:'modele_id='+modeleID,
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(result){
    $('#prod'+modeleID).text(result.NOM);
    $('#prod'+modeleID).attr('data-img', 'assets/img/produits/' + result.IMAGEPATH);
    }
  });
```

i use this function for the hover content :

```
$('[data-toggle="popover-hover"]').popover({
    html: true,
    trigger: 'hover',
    placement: 'bottom',
    content: function () { return '<img src="' + $(this).data('img') + '" />'; }
});
```

but it doesn't fired up because my dynamic data is not find in the begin of my page. I need to use some document ready syntax like this :

```
$(document)('[data-toggle="popover-hover"]').popover({
    html: true,
    trigger: 'hover',
    placement: 'bottom',
    content: function () { return '<img src="' + $(this).data('img') + '" />'; }
});
```

but I get some syntax error, any advice?

Comment: What is the syntax error you recieve?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...) is not a function

Comment: Maybe you're using another library that conflicts with jQuery. $ is shorthand for jQuery. But other libraries also use $. So if you're using one of those you'll need to type jQuery instead of $.

Comment: only jquery nothing else.

Comment: Try using `jQuery(...)...` instead of `$(...)...`

Comment: Where is the link to jquery? Try putting it in the head, or make sure it's before all other script, *including yours*.

Comment: Do you include Tippy.js? `popover` is a function from that library...